# how to exclude the linux cached memory from the monitoring and only monitor the application consumed memory

Tags: linux, github, vmware, snmp, nagios

We are using GItHub Enterprise as our source code management system and its installed as an appliance in Vmware Esxi.

For monitoring purpose we are using 2 tools for getting the performance metrics.

1) Nagios over SNMP ( GHE provides the resource metric by default over SNMP)

2) vROPS for montoring.

But its noticed that GHE will create a much cached memory which will result in unwanted alerts. There is 4.6 G of cached memory, how to configure threshold for GHE (used-cached) memory instead of just used memory.

Current memory usage on the system is:

```
free -h

total used free shared buffers cached Mem:
15G 14G 909M 1.5M 375M 4.6G
-/+ buffers/cache: 9.8G 5.9G
Swap: 0B 0B 0B
```

But in monitoring side is there any way to exclude these linux consumed memory and only the GHe consumed memory alone?

Comment: @jww: This is on-topic. We can determine what standard (or non-standard) OID will provide the requested information, if indeed it is available. This is normal in [tag:snmp]. SNMP relates to programming as it is a way to communicate between different software entities.

Comment: Which MIB(s) are you using at the moment, @saran?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - if you notice, the question is *"how to configure threshold for GHE (used-cached) memory instead of just used memory."* It looks like a run of the mill server configuration question with no material intersection with software (to me). Questions about configuring Nagios and vROPS are better asked on other sites. Using OIDs does not change it.

Comment: @jww If you notice, the question is about how to extract the information "quantity of memory consumed" rather than "quantity of memory consumed and/or cached", via SNMP. Using OIDs is at the very crux of it and no server configuration is involved.

Comment: GHE- GitHub Enterprise appliance. We are getting alert on Nagios and vROPS for memory consumption due to the increased amount of cache memory. As we understood, its linux behavior like that and we are looking for a solution to exclude this cache memory so that we wont get ant wrong alert because of that

Comment: our aim is to configure threshold for (used-cached)  memory instead of just used memory in nagios monitoring

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. You are correct, we are looking whether Nagios can give alerts only for (used-cached) memory instead of just used memory...We followed these steps from GHE side:-  https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/admin/installation/monitoring-using-snmp

Comment: So what OID are you using at the moment, @saran?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit , as my knowledge the Nagios team is using the in Nagios SNMP Memory check plugin and OID "hrMemorySize.0"

Comment: Can you link to this plugin? Be precise. There are many, many plugins.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They used check_snmp

Comment: You are not being precise. "They used check_snmp" ok. Who is they? Can you link to the exact Nagios plugin in use? What OID did they request with it? We need these details or you cannot be helped.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we used  check_snmp_mem.pl  -H <HOSTNAME> -l <login> -x <password> -X <privPassword> -L SHA, AES  -m Physical -w 10 -c 5 0

Comment: any suggestion ?